# Dynamically responsive grid-style container in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, containers, css-grid

In my application a user is able to input text and click a button to append a new 'span' to the DOM (within a container) containing their inputted text. I want these spans to have as much width as needed to fit the given user inputted text (you can assume the user wont input something longer than the container's width). I would also want the container to fit as many spans as possible within in a row; and if a span needs more room than is left in the current row -> go to the row below (see the last two lines of the picture).

What kind of CSS would I need to add to my container as well as the spans within it to achieve the organization below?

Please Note: the width of this container is fixed, but the height grows as needed to fit new text filled spans

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per you mockup, You can achieve your task by two way:

- Use flex CSS3 property
- Use CSS3 property width auto and float left in span class.

let span class="class-name"

```
.class-name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

In this span class, you can add more property as per your need.

Comment: what would I need to put in the container class? just display: flex?

Comment: I did not add anything else to the container class and this seemed to have worked. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to use flex property for your layout. Here is the basic code:

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

Comment: Neither `width: auto` nor `float: left` add anything since an _inline_ element by default both size by content and align left. Furthermore, if the parent has `display: flex` (which the tag list kind of suggest), none of the suggested settings will have any affect.

Comment: I added everything you said would not work, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with the CSS3 flex property:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 20rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* otherwise it will try to fit everything on one line */
  justify-content: space-between; /* alternatives are space-evenly or space-around*/
}
```

see this [pen](https://codepen.io/RolandStuder/pen/rvPreR), with flex you have the advantage that you have better control over how this width of the container is uses, with the float solution you cannot justify the content, it will all stick to the left and leave unused space on the right.